# Application crashes while scaling QImage

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

For one specific tiff file, my app which tries to display it, crashes. Even Windows10 Photo viewer and Photos can not display the picture correctly. File is exported by GIMP 2.10. I did try open file with GIMP 2.10.34, successfully. Unfortunately I can not upload it, it is customer's data. I do use QT 5.12.12.

Code:

```
int MyTiffImage::getRGBARasterData( uint8 *&o_pRasterData, uint32 &o_width, uint32 &o_height,
                                       uint16 &o_spp, uint16 &o_bps,
                                       const int i_dirIdx, const int i_parentDirIdx )
{
    // some code

    // old allocation: app crashed while assigning value to o_pRasterData
    //int l_rowBytes = getRowBytesNumber( l_width, o_spp, o_bps );
    //o_pRasterData = (uint8 *)_TIFFmalloc(l_rowBytes*l_height * sizeof(uint8));

    // new allocation solved crash here, but moved it to scaling image
    int rowBytes_test = getRowBytesNumber(l_width, o_spp, o_bps);
    
    tmsize_t l_rowBytes = (tmsize_t)getRowBytesNumber(l_width, o_spp, o_bps);
    tmsize_t l_size = l_rowBytes * (tmsize_t)l_height * (tmsize_t)sizeof(uint8);

    if (l_size < l_rowBytes)
        return(-1);
    o_pRasterData = (uint8 *)_TIFFmalloc(l_size);// allocated
    
    if( o_pRasterData == NULL )
        return( -1 );
    if( TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented(m_pTif,l_width,l_height,(uint32 *)o_pRasterData,l_orient,0) == 0 )
    {
        return( -1 );
    }
    o_width = l_width;
    o_height = l_height;
    return( 0 );
}
```

and then:

```
int32 MyViewerBasePlugin::drawImage(tnt_id_t i_ViewerId, tnt_id_t i_ModelId, tnt_id_t i_ModelItemId, int32** o_ppaTextureIds, int32& o_CountTextures, uint32 i_MaxCountTextures)
{
    wglGetCurrentContext();
    void* image = m_Images.getValue(i_ModelId, i_ModelItemId, MyImageObj::BACKGROUND);
    MyImageObj* imgObj = (MyImageObj*) image;
    QImage img = imgObj->getImage();

    if(!img.isNull())
    {
      int l_textureSize[1];
      l_textureSize[0] = 0;
      glGetError();
      glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, l_textureSize);
      int err = glGetError();
      if(err != 0)
      {
        l_textureSize[0] = 64;
      }
      std::cout << "GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: " << l_textureSize[0] << std::endl;
      // IMPROVE DETAILS
      int cols = (img.width() / l_textureSize[0]) + 1;
      int rows = (img.height() / l_textureSize[0]) + 1;
      
      // int l_textureCount[1];
      // l_textureCount[0] = 0;
      // glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, l_textureCount);

      // if vga does not support 16 textures -> use only one as fallback
      if(cols*rows > i_MaxCountTextures) {
        cols = 1;
        rows = 1;
      }

      // for performance reasons, limit the texture size to 4096
      // but only if more than one texture is supported
      if(l_textureSize[0] > 4096 && (cols*rows) > 1) {
        l_textureSize[0] = 4096;
      }

      double avWidth = l_textureSize[0] * cols;
      double avHeight = l_textureSize[0] * rows;

      if(avWidth > img.width() || avHeight > img.height()) {
        avWidth = img.width();
        avHeight = img.height();
      }

      QImage newImg = img.scaled(avWidth, avHeight);// Crash was moved here
      //QImage newImg = img.scaledToWidth(avWidth, Qt::FastTransformation);

      // other code
  }
    return( 0 );
}
```

creating QImage

```
QImage MyImageObj::getImage()
{
  if(m_image.isNull())
  {
    if(m_spp == 1 && m_bps == 1)
    {
      m_image = QImage(m_data.data(), m_width, m_height, m_bytesPerRow, QImage::Format_Mono);
    }
    else if(m_layertype == 0 ||
            m_layertype == 1 ||
            m_layertype == 2 ||
            m_layertype == 3 ||
            m_layertype == 5 ||
            m_layertype == 6 ||
            m_layertype == 7 ||
            m_layertype == 8 ||
            m_layertype == 9)
    {
      QImage swap;
      if(m_scaleX != 0 || m_scaleY != 0)
      {
        QImage tmp = QImage(m_data.data(), m_width, m_height, m_width*3, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        swap = tmp.scaled(m_width*m_scaleX, m_height*m_scaleY);
        swap.invertPixels();
      }
      else
      {
        swap = QImage(m_data.data(), m_width, m_height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        swap.invertPixels();
      }
      m_image = swap.rgbSwapped();
    }
    else
    {
      m_image = QImage(m_data.data(), m_width, m_height, m_bytesPerRow, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
        //QImage::Format_RGBA64
    }
  }

  return m_image;
}
```

some real data values:

```
i_Width:81118
i_Height:13244
l_originRowBytes:324472
l_rowBytes:324472
l_originSize:2339872

QImage::Format_RGBA8888 
qSize:4297307168 // memory allocated
```

If I try not to scale but copy the image `QImage newImg = img.copy(0, 0, 100, 100);`, app crashes as well.

[image properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSmDe.png)

After deeper investigation, I have found the problem. `QVector` can handle only data with size lower than `INT_MAX`. `m_data.size() = 2,339,872` although I allocated 4,297,307,168. I miss exactly 2^32.

```
void myImageObj::addData(unsigned char *i_pData, unsigned int i_bytesPerRow, unsigned int i_width, unsigned int i_height, float i_scaleX, float i_scaleY, unsigned short int i_spp, unsigned short int i_bps, int i_layertype, int i_PosX, int i_PosY)
{
  if(i_layertype == BACKGROUND)
    m_data = QVector<unsigned char>(i_bytesPerRow*i_height);
  else
    m_data = QVector<unsigned char>(i_bytesPerRow);
  //some code
  int mds = m_data.size();// only size of int allowed!!!
  std::copy(i_pData, i_pData + m_data.size(),
        stdext::checked_array_iterator<unsigned char*>(
          m_data.data(), m_data.size()));
}
```

Maybe `QList` can help, or I have to update to Qt6 (paid).

Comment: `4297307168` -- Is your application 32-bit or 64-bit?  If it's 32-bit, there is little to no chance allocating this memory in a contiguous block will work.

Comment: *Even Windows10 Photo viewer and Photos can not display it correctly.* -- Before you waste your time, is there *any* application that can display the image?  Maybe IrfanView or some other app?

Comment: Do I understand well that you want to use picture with size 81118 x 13244 pixels, with size over 4.2 GB? Are you sure you really want this?

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, yes, in GIMP 2.10.34, question edited.

Comment: Hi @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager, that exactly the point. How to manage the memory?

Comment: @know *At first, app crashed while o_pRasterData = (uint8 *)_TIFFmalloc(l_rowBytes*l_height * sizeof(uint8));* -- You should have investigated *why* it crashed there before trying random things.  This is a libtiff function, with full source code available.  Once you figure out the *why*, then it becomes clearer on what should be done (maybe libtiff cannot handle such images).

Comment: I guess I need to allocate 4.2GB of memory to read whole image. I need to zoom in/out it later, so it makes no sense to display only part of it. Or I would need read it every time while zooming/moving the picture in view pane. `o_pRasterData = (uint8 *)_TIFFmalloc(l_rowBytesl_height * sizeof(uint8));` did not simply allocate enough memory. There might be some memory limitation in `QImage::scaled`, but I can not find relevant info

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My guess is that it crashed because he tried to calculate the size as `int`, which is 32-bit even on 64-bit system. It overflowed probably resulting in negative number. So the allocation crashed. This is what I assume that happened.

Comment: @know Can we see the part of code where you construct the `QImage`? Or did I overlook it?

Comment: @know Without looking at Qt code, I assume that the problem is that Qt keeps all array indices usually as signed `int`. Therefore the maximum size is 2,147,483,647 bytes. You request twice as much. It is just my guess...

If I were you, I would try to do some optimizations before you create the `QImage`. But it depends on your usecase. What is the expected scaled size you want? Maybe you could precalculate already scaled image before you create the QImage. Maybe merge 4 pixels into 1. That would result in 1 GB image, which is still very big but probably manageable with `QImage`.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager, thanks for your ideas. I updated question, added creating of QImage. Expected size depends on window size and screen resolution. So with 4K monitor around 3500x1500px. File degradation is not the right way. It displays technical drawing, should be precise after zoom.

Comment: @know If it is a precise technical drawing, then you probably will also need your custom scaling algorithm... I guess it mostly contains black and white lines (or not?) with a certain width. Scaling this may result in very unsatisfactory results, the result may result in virtually invisible lines (if they were too thin in the original drawing). Did you try the scaling quality on a smaller image to prove it scales well?

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager scaling might be next chapter to improve. You are right, this one is black & white drawing, although exported as RGBA8888. Thank you for your ideas, I need to investigate more. I won`t give up :)